# perl using a hash to filter another hashes contents

Tags: perl, hash, filter

I have a symbol download from a database that produces this populates the symbol hash just fine. WHen I sort the keys I get this

```
foreach $symbol ( sort keys %symbol_hash ) {
    print "$symbol\n ";
}
A AA AAL AAPL ABBV ABT ABT_SPIN ABX ACI ACN ACT ADBE ADI ADM ADSK AEIS AEO AES AET AFAM AGN AGU AIG AKAM AKS ALL ALNY ALR ALU AMAT AMGN AMP AMZN ANF ANN ANR APA APC ARCC
```

I have a unix config file which contains alot of information for many processes.

This is the config file

```
# Tick Size
# tr -d \  | sort -u
TickSizePostOpen = 1.00
TickSize = {
  penny1 = {
    TickSize = 0.00
    members = {
      IWM
      QQQ
      SPY
      SPY_TEST
    }
  }
  penny = {
    TickSize = </0.000/0.00/0.00
    members = {
A
AA
AAL
AAPL
ABT
ABT_SPIN
ZNGA
    }
  }
  notpenny = {
    TickSize = </9/9.99/9.99
  }
}
BIPP.QuoterOx = {
  Cup1and2 = {
    BIPP.QuoterOx = BIPP-ox-1
    members = {
      Cup_1
      Cup_2
    }
  }
 TRAP.PxByGroup = 1
TRAP.Px = {
  group1 = {
    TRAP.Px = OPTxxxxxx
    members = {
      px.TRAP.1
    }
  }
  group2 = {
    TRAP.Px = OPTxxxxxx
    members = {
      px.TRAP.2
    }
  }
TRAP.QuoterOx = {
  Cup0 = {
    TRAP.QuoterOx = QESxxxxx
    members = {
      Cup_0
      Cup_99
    }
  }
  Cup1and4and10 = {
    TRAP.QuoterOx = ise-ox-1-4-10-dti
    members = {
      Cup_1
      Cup_4
      Cup_10
    }
  }
Cup56 = {
    TRAP.AuctionOx = ise-ox-56-ecl
     members = {
      Cup_56
    }
  }
}
TRAP.RotateQuote = {
  rotatenames = {
    TRAP.RotateQuote = 1
      members = {
              AAPL
              ADY
              AEIS
              AFAM
              AGP
              ALNY
              ZINC
      }
  }
}
Underlying = {
  Cup0 = {
    Underlying = MHR
    members = {
      Cup_0
    }
  }
  g1 = {
    Underlying = CEL
    members = {
      Cup_1
    }
  }
}
BIPP.Px = {
    group1 = {
        BIPP.Px = BOXPXMHR1
        members = {
            px.BIPP.1
        }
    }
    group2 = {
        BIPP.Px = BOXPXMHR2
         members = {
            px.BIPP.2
        }
    }
}
TWIG.Px = {
   AB = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR1
   members = {
     A
     B
  }
 }
   CD = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR2
   members = {
     C
     D
    }
 }
   NOPQR = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR6
   members = {
      N
     O
      P
     Q
     R
   }
 }
   STUV = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR7
       members = {
          S
          T
          U
           V
       }
   }
   WXYZ = {
   TWIG.Px = TWIGPXMHR8
       members = {
           W
           X
           Y
           Z
      }
   }
}
```

What I am trying to do is download symbols from a database, populate a symbol hash(which works), then load in the config file file, parse it down to its barest elements and using the symbol hash as a filter, populate the penny hash. So if an element from the stripped down config file is in the symbol hash, put it in the penny hash.

---

```
#!/perl/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dbUser = 'yeah';
my $dbPass = 'boy';        # <--- was missing closing single quote
my $dbSid  = 'yeah.boy';
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:$dbSid", "$dbUser", "$dbPass" ) or die("Couldn't connect: $!");

my $penny_file  = "/data/wowmom.cfg";
my %penny_hash  = ();
my %symbol_hash = ();
my $query       = "select alotof stuff from yeah.boy ";
if ( !$dbh ) {
    print "Error connecting to Database: $DBI::errstr\n";
}
my $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "\n\nCould not prepare statement: " . dbh->errstr;
$cur_msg->execute();
while ( my @row = $cur_msg->fetchrow_array ) {
    $symbol_hash{ $row[0] } = 1;
}

open( my $penny_fh, '<', "$penny_file" ) or die "Can't open $penny_file for reading: $!";
while (<$penny_fh>) {
    next unless /\S/;
    #print unless /[#{}=]/ ; # try this  - the parse works!
    if ( !/[#{}=]/ ) {
        if ( $symbol_hash{$_} ) {
            $penny_hash{$_} = 1;    # does not populate
        }
    }
}

#foreach my $symbol ( sort keys %symbol_hash ) {
#    print "$symbol\n ";
#} # works

print Dumper( \%penny_hash );    #does not work
#print Dumper(\%symbol_hash) ; # works
#foreach my $penny ( sort keys %penny_hash ) {
#    print "$penny\n ";
#}
```

the Dumper(\%penny_hash) prints nothing.

Comment: This is probably just a copy/paste error, but you're missing a closing single quote in the line `my $dbPass = 'boy;`

Comment: You're not `chomp`ing the lines in `$penny_file`, so you're comparing `foo` to `foo\n`, for example.

Comment: Does anyone have a canonical answer for forgetting to `chomp` ?

Comment: @RobEarl I don't think I've seen one general enough to be used as a canonical. Care to write one? If you do, I think not `chomp`ing `STDIN` deserves special mention (if not its own question).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571878/why-does-my-file-content-user-input-not-match-missing-chomp-canonical

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input:

```
while (<$penny_fh>) {
    chomp;        # <-- remove line endings before string comparison
```