# Why does my file content/user input not match? (missing chomp canonical)

Tags: perl

I'm reading from a file/`STDIN` and looking for a specific value:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $find = 'def';    
while (<DATA>) {
    if ($_ eq $find) {
        print "Found: $_\n"; # Never reached!
    }
}

__DATA__
abc
def
xyz
```

Why is the condition never matched?

Comment: If anyone knows an already existing, general "Forgot to chomp my input" question, feel free to flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: This type of question is difficult to find a canonical duplicate for.  The OP's rarely have a clue what's going wrong, so their title/questions of course don't mention chomp or line endings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Dumper) can be used to more closely examine the variables:

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

print Dumper $_, $find;
```

Outputs, e.g.

```
$VAR1 = "def\n";
$VAR2 = "def";
```

You have to remove the `\n` character that `<DATA>` reads into `$_`. The simplest way to do it is the [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $find = 'def';    
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ eq $find) {
        print "Found: $_\n"; # Never reached!
    }
}

__DATA__
abc
def
xyz
```