# Perl script can't match string in array despite me knowing a match is there

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a Perl script that allows the user to enter a list of parameters as an argument with the command line using the -p flag. A subroutine in the script then loops through a longer set of parameters and checks if any of them match the parameters passed in with the -p flag.

Since it's possible to enter multiple parameters on the command line, the strings get stored in the variable `$ARGV{'-p'}` (I am using [`Getopt::Euclid`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Euclid)). I convert this variable into an array and store it in a variable called `@parlist`. However, no matter what method I seem to use, I can never seem to get the script to recognize a match between a string (stored in a variable) and an element of the array, even when I print out the contents of both and see the exact matches myself.

My code:

```
#parameter being matched as an argument of the subroutine
my $pline = $_[0];

#parameter list as command line argument
my @parlist = @{$ARGV{'-p'}};
print "parlist: @parlist\n";

#extract parameter name from parameter line
$pline =~ /^.*?\._*?(.*)=.*$/;
my $pname = ($1);
print "pname: $pname\n";

#this doesn't find a match
my %p = map {$_ => 1 } @parlist;
if (exists $p{$pname}) {
    print "Found it!\n";
}

#neither does this
my $match = grep { $_ eq $pname } @parlist;
print "$match\n";

#this doesn't either
if (grep { /$pname/ } @{$ARGV{'-p'}} ) {
    print "Found it!\n";
}
```

Please note that the regex works fine. The two print lines at the top let me confirm when there is an actual match between the variable and the array, but the match checking still don't seem to work. The script is called like this:

`./script -p streams_pool_size`

Several loops through the subroutine might look something like this:

```
parlist: streams_pool_size
pname: java_pool_size

parlist: streams_pool_size
pname: streams_pool_size

parlist: streams_pool_size
pname: nls_language
```

The second set of results would indicate a match to me, or at least that is my perception of it.

Pulling my hair out trying to find what I'm doing wrong here. I'm sure the answer is right in from of me and I just haven't seen it yet.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of input? Also, no need for the brackets in the line `my $pname = ($1);`.

Comment: Add output to question, `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%ARGV, $pline`

Comment: Just added example input and output. I will also add your Dumper code in there to see if it gives different results.

Comment: What is your regex `/^.*?\._*?(.*)=.*$/` supposed to match? It would help to put it in an `if` statement too: `my $pname; if ($pline =~ /^.*?\._*?(.*)=.*$/) { $pname = $1; }` then check `$pname` is set.

Comment: Just a side note: this is why modules like [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) exist. Parsing command line arguments yourself is error-prone and a big PITA.

Comment: Where is the associated POD for this?  Euclid parses the POD to determine what options can be passed, without that it probably won't work at all.

Comment: Actually, can you use `use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper \%ARGV, $pline;` instead?

Comment: The variable $pline contains both the parameter name and the value. The regex pulls out just the name and stores it in $pname. I know that $pname is getting set specifically because I print it to the command line and am able to see that it has a value. I have added the Perl POD for your reference as well.

Comment: Could you give some identified examples of the input, i.e. `$pline = parameter_name3`, `$ARGV{'-p'} = ['pip','pap','pop'];`? It would also be helpful if you added identifiers to your print statements, i.e `say "pname: $pname"`

Comment: Ah, I think you found it, mpapec! Dumper shows `$VAR2 = 'streams_pool_size '`, indicating an invisible space at the end of $pname that I could not detect.

Comment: @NeutyBooty You should make that an answer and accept it.

Comment: That's almost certainly a newline since your output has one too many newlines after `print "pname: $pname\n";`. @ikegami's suggestion above would confirm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my file content/user input not match? (missing chomp canonical)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571878/why-does-my-file-content-user-input-not-match-missing-chomp-canonical)

Comment: @RobEarl, I thought the blank line came from `print "$match\n";`, but that should print `0`. The output did not come from the code the OP posted, so who knows.

Comment: The new lines were irrelevant, they were added by a separate part of the program. Should have mentioned that in the question, but the real cause is explained in the answer.

Comment: @ikegami I had thought one of them came from there too which still left one unaccounted for (question has been edited now so there are only two rather than three)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always use `Data::Dumper` when trying to print the contents of variables and arrays for testing purposes. Using `print` will not show invisible spaces in the strings that will cause mismatches. In the above code, the Dumper output was:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '-parameter' => [
                            'streams_pool_size'
                          ],
          '-p' => $VAR1->{'-parameter'},
        };
$VAR2 = 'streams_pool_size ';
```

The space at the end of `$VAR2` was causing the mismatch.

Comment: Just Data::Dumper isn't good enough; set `$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1` to actually see all the characters unambiguously (e.g. backspaces as "\b")